# Is there a reason for keeping max_file_uploads at a low value?

Tags: php, file-upload

So while configuring a server for uploading files I noticed the default for max_file_uploads is 20 files. Is there any reason to keep this at a low value or is it safe to up it to 100 files?

Comment: Do you need it at 100? If not leave it at 20 if yes then change it to 100?!

Comment: if the default value was high it could course resource issues and people would blame php.

Comment: I'm wanting to allow the users to upload as many files as they need at once so they don't have to just keep going back if they need to upload more then 10. So I just need to know if there is any downside to allowing them to upload up to 100 files at once.

Answer (score -1):

This will depends about your server resources (bandwidth, memory, cpu, etc) If you have a powerfull server and you need to download at the same time 100 files, go head and change it to 100 otherwise keep it as low possible

Comment: Actually, this setting has nothing to do with bandwidth, memory, or CPU.  This directive has nothing to do with the file size (bandwidth), files are streamed directly to disk so there isn't much memory used, and CPU is minimal as again it's all IO.

Comment: Downloading 100 files (1GB each, I am sure it will affect your server performance. In addition it will have 100 connections downloading at the same time. I really believe this can affect your server resources (bandwidth, memory, or CPU) But I am not an expert.

Comment: `max_file_uploads` doesn't specify size.  The 100 files could be 1KB each.  If you want to control size, you need a different directive.  And, there are not 100 connections at the same time.  `max_file_uploads` is per-request.  The files are sent serially.  If you want to protect server resources, you need other configuration than `max_file_uploads`.

Comment: Yes I know, that is why I also keep `upload_max_filesize` as low as possible. The question is: `Is there a reason for keeping max_file_uploads at a low value?` and my answer (in my opinion) still true. Can you imagining having by default `max_file_uploads = 10000` and `upload_max_filesize=2M` (default value)?  At this point you might have 10000 connections at the same time downloading 20GB (in total). Again, I am not an expert. I might be wrong

Comment: `max_file_uploads` could be `1`, and you could still have 10,000 connections at the same time uploading files.  It's per-request.